# Attributes on object property in ontology

Tags: rdf, semantics, owl, ontology, reification

How to associate attributes with object properties in ontology ?

I have come across a way in which object property can be defined as a class. But this approach makes defining rules difficult. Is there any other way ?

Comment: This is rather broad and vague. Can you give an example of what you're after, how you've tried to actually model it, and the specific problem you have with that approach?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use blank nodes to handle extra properties, as the objectproperty don't have the possibility.

Otherwise you have to add a new class for the relationship, so what you currently have as a objectproperty becomes a class, and you get a new objectproperty for the relationship between your old class and old objectproperty (which now becomes a class)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class for my object property and I have kept the original object property as it is. Attributes are defined on the class. Rules can be defined on the object property as we are used to do it and attributes can be fetched from the class which will be treated as internal class.

I have used OWL API for this.